# automation test in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, automation-testing

I'm trying to run pipeline for automation test with python  script, actually virtual Environment i need to install in project/src location.
but it is by default creating virtual Environment in gitlab below location.
home/gitlab-runner/builds/CzgiGr2e/0/digitalplatform/projectfolder/projectfolder/bin/pyvenv
But i want to install virtual environment in project/src location and activate (on linux server)

**present using commands**:

- pyhton3 -v
- pip install virtualenv
- virtualenv projectname
- source projectname/bin/activate
- pip3 install -r requirements.txt
- pip3 install selenium
- pip install pytest
- pip install requests

Comment: You don't care where your venv is installed, giving that you `[source] activate` it first

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.